# For entry and entryValues, can one mix string and integer arrays in ListPreference?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Can one do this for a ListPreference? (target API 19)

```
<string-array name="alert_type">
    <item>regular intervals</item>
    <item>one time</item>
</string-array>
<integer-array name="alert_type_value">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
</integer-array>
```

I am getting this error. when I change the integer-array to a string-array, then I do **not** get the error below.

```
05-10 20:54:52.179: W/dalvikvm(32634): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bef1f8)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.preference.ListPreference.findIndexOfValue(ListPreference.java:215)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.preference.ListPreference.getValueIndex(ListPreference.java:224)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.preference.ListPreference.getEntry(ListPreference.java:202)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.preference.ListPreference.getSummary(ListPreference.java:148)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.preference.Preference.onBindView(Preference.java:507)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:453)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:222)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2222)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1774)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1611)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2052)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11484)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4229)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1502)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11484)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4229)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11484)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4229)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1502)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11484)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4229)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11484)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4229)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1671)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
05-10 20:54:52.209: E/AndroidRuntime(32634):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with the normal `ListPreference`. However, [this blog post](http://kmansoft.com/2011/01/02/implementing-a-styleable-preference-for-a-list-of-integers/) shows how to make your own custom list preference that will accept an integer array, and there's even full source code at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the link; Kostya is a top programmer but I think mine is an easier solution

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: I dont know if it could be considered a solution - a workaround, maybe. I list it below.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for me was to translate from string to integer and back in the listeners.

from string to int

```
intValue = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(ALERT_TYPE,"-1"));
alertTypePreference.setSummary(intValue == -1 ? "click to set" : (intValue == AlertTable.PERIODIC_TYPE ? "regular intervals" : "one time"));
```

and back

```
    alertTypePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (newValue.equals(Integer.toString(AlertTable.PERIODIC_TYPE))) {
            setEnabledAlertType(AlertTable.PERIODIC_TYPE);
        } else .....
        return true; 
    }
});
```